# Time complexity of aggregate function in SQL with Index

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I've created a SQL Index on a field COLUMN_NAME. Suppose there are N rows in the table.

Is the time required to find the `MIN(COLUMN_NAME)` or `MAX(COLUMN_NAME)` same as finding `WHERE COLUMN_NAME=XYZ`

Comment: `min()` and `max()` are probably faster than `where column  = ..`. But it also depends on the DBMS product being used. The implementation and usage of indexes varies substantially between different database products.

Comment: @SandeepYadav . . . They are no comparable.  `MIN()` and `MAX()` are used in aggregation queries.  `WHERE` can be used in any query.  If you have a question about performance, you should at least show the queries you care about.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've written what I wanted in simplest words,

exact queries:
SELECT MIN(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TBL or 
SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TBL

are these faster or slower than 

SELECT COLUMN_NAME2 FROM TBL WHERE COLUMN_NAME1=XYZ

Comment: @SandeepYadav . . . Why would you be comparing the performance of queries that return *different* results?  You should write the query that produces the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just wanted to know which will run faster. Having Max value of some column stored somewhere and querying with WHERE, or selecting with MAX(), but as User "a_horse_with_no_name" pointed out, when the column is indexed, finding min() and max() are faster than WHERE so, hence the answer I needed.